# Geometry from wkt/polygon using geotools

Tags: postgis, geotools

I have polygon string ,how can I find geometry by giving polygon as input,Is there any function like we have ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON ....) in postgis ,which give geometry.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jts/geometry.html) use a `WKTReader`:

```
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

    WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);
    Point point = (Point) reader.read("POINT (1 1)");
```